# Set environment variables within SSH Session

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a situation where I have a host machine where I need certain applications installed with side by side versions. Obviously only one can get added to the exports to run by default. As an example we might say it's Python 2.7, Python 3.5, & Python 3.7.

I need to be able to establish an SSH connection to the host, where each connection can set the correct path for the specific version that is required. Is there an easy way to do this. The key here is that each connection cannot affect either the host itself or other connections. Someone running on the host itself shouldn't break because the path was updated by a remote connection.

Comment: Can you just set `PATH` after logging in via SSH. Like `export PATH=$PATH:/addition/to/path`? That will only affect that shell and its descendents

Comment: Only affecting the specific shell is what I care about. The host itself would have the path to one of the installs already... so I'm not sure would what you mentioned `export PATH=$PATH:/addition/to/path` work to override just the specific install... so say the Host defaulted to Python 3.5 but I want 2.7 in the shell...

Comment: I see. So `PATH` when you log in already has a path to a directory that has an executable `python` of a particular version, but you want to specify a different path that also contains an executable `python` but a different version so you are stuck with removing one directory from path and setting a new one. Can you just overwrite the full path variable when you log in like `export PATH=/usr/bin:/blah/blah/blah:/foo/bar:/path/to/my/python/version` fully ignoring whatever PATH was?

Comment: One way I've dealt with different python versions for a session is to have each python installed with the full version name like `/usr/bin/python2.7` and `/usr/bin/python3.6` then in the `.bashrc` or `.profile` for the user I use aliases to specify which version like `alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7` so that alias is picked up on login. This way I don't have to monkey with path.

Comment: the applications are absolutely installed separately like you mentioned... I'm just looking for what's the best way to deal with it within the confines of a specific shell that won't affect other shells which may be running with the same user.

Comment: How do the scripts invoke the tool - do they use 'python ...', or do they use the '#! /path/to/python/...' or some other form ?

Answer (score 1):

For the case of multiple (python and other) hierarchies, and assuming that the tools are invokes by the tool name (python ...), prepending the preferred path to the system path will provide a way to specify per-instance tool setting, without having side effect between jobs.

```
ssh ... 'PATH=/path/to/python3.1/bin:$PATH command'
```

Depending on the number of tools, and complexity of the setup, you might want to implement this as a wrapper

```
ssh ... '/path/to/run-with-pkgs python-3.2 pkg2 -- command'
```

With the pkg-setup script source various config script. Something along the lines of:

```
run-with-pkgs

#! /bin/bash
while [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" != "--" ] ; do
   source "/path/to/setup.d/$1.sh"
   shift
done
if [ "$1" = "--" ] ; then
    shift
    exec "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Note that the `-a` argument to `[` is flagged obsolescent in the current version of [the POSIX standard for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). `[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" != -- ]` is better form. I'd also suggest quoting the `"$1"` to prevent word-splitting and glob expansion; it's certainly never *less* correct than failing to do so.